# Type Cannot create a generic array of List<FooClass>

Tags: java, list, collections

Suppose I have class FooClass.

```
public class FooClass {
}
```

The following line gives me the following compile error:

```
// Note I want to create an array of length 4 of Lists of FooClass
List<FooClass> runs[]=new List<FooClass>[4];
```

```
Cannot create a generic array of List<FooClass> ...
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) collection is not the same as [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
// if you want create a List of FooClass (you can use any List implementation)
List<FooClass> runs = new ArrayList<FooClass>();

// if you want create array of FooClass
FooClass[] runs = new FooClass[4];
```

**UPD:**

If you want to create array of lists, you should:

1. Create array
2. Fill this array in with List instances

Example:

```
List<FooClass>[] runs = new List[4];
for (int i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
    runs[i] = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: I am not the down-voter, but I think the OP is asking for creating array of lists rather than a single list.

Comment: Yes @Eng.Fouad (btw I'm not the down voter either) - but yes I'm trying to create array of lists rather than a single list.

Answer (score 4):

It's not good idea to mix Generics and Array. Generics doesn't retain type information at run time so creating an array of generics fails.

Comment: mmmm I think this might be it

Answer (score -1):

List should not be declared as array. It should be:

```
List<FooClass> runs=new ArrayList<FooClass>(4);
```

or

```
List<FooClass> runs=new ArrayList<FooClass>();
```

**Edit**: you can try `List<ConfigParser> runs[] = new List[4];`. But why do you need array of Lists?

Also as @rai.skumar has mentioned, Generic information is not retained during run time because of Type Erasure.

Comment: Hi @rajesh, I actually want to create an array of Lists of FooClass.

Comment: I have a particular use case where I have 4 lists that I need to process

Comment: wow that worked. hmmm if you update your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I need an array of lists for my program. Actually, I need a multidimensional array of lists.